# Converting agentset into list in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo, modeling, agent

I'm writing some code to vaccinate individuals in a population where flu is circulating. There are two kinds of vaccines (named HOV and HEV in the code); the HOV is already done. What I tried/wanted to do was convert the agentset of blue turtles into a list, that I could then iterate over one turtle at a time. I need to do this because the HEV condition has to give a slightly different vaccine to each blue turtle (i.e. the flu strain in each vaccine has to be slightly different). However, NetLogo is highlighting "foreach [vax-turtles]" with an error message that says "Expected a literal value."

My code is below, the "if vaccine = "HEV"" piece of code is what I need help with:

```
extensions [csv]
globals [strain_list_list epidemic-threshold cumulative-infections proportion-of-infection currently-infected peak-prevalence vax-strain]
turtles-own [infection-period infection-number tflu-strain immune-label ant-distance cross-immunity]
patches-own [fomite-age pflu-strain]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-turtles
  set strain_list_list (list t-sorted-strain-list)
  print strain_list_list
  reset-ticks
end

to-report t-sorted-strain-list
  report map [i -> [tflu-strain] of i] sort turtles
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles 100
  ask turtles [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ask turtles [set color white set infection-number 0 set immune-label -999999999999 set tflu-strain -999999999999]
  ask one-of turtles [set color red set infection-period 0 set infection-number 1 set immune-label 0 set tflu-strain 0]
  if vaccine = "HOV" [
    ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      set vax-strain (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
    [set vax-strain (-1 * random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
  ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue set immune-label vax-strain]
  ]
  if vaccine = "HEV" [
    let vax-turtles (list turtles with [color = blue])
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue] 
    foreach [vax-turtles] [
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      set vax-strain (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
    [set vax-strain (-1 * random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
      ]
    ]
  set epidemic-threshold "no"
  set cumulative-infections 0
  set peak-prevalence 0
end

to go
  if ticks = flu-season-length [stop]
  move-infecteds
  move-uninfecteds
  transmit
  mutate
  update-immunity
  track-infecteds
  set cumulative-infections (count turtles with [infection-period = 1] + cumulative-infections)
  set proportion-of-infection (100 - (count turtles with [immune-label = -999999999999]))
  set currently-infected (count turtles with [infection-period = 1])
  csv:to-file "strains_each_tick.csv" strain_list_list
  set strain_list_list lput t-sorted-strain-list strain_list_list
  tick
end

to move-uninfecteds ;; uninfected turtles move faster than infected ones
  ask turtles with [color = white or color = blue] [
    right random 360
    forward 5
  ]
end

to move-infecteds ;; infected turtles move slower than uninfected ones and always transmit infection to patches before they leave them
  ask turtles with [color = red] [
  if pcolor = black [
      set pcolor red
    set fomite-age 0
    set pflu-strain tflu-strain]
  right random 360
  forward 3
]
end

to transmit ;; uninfected turtles are infected by fomites (red patches) with some probability. immune-labelling currently first infection
  ask turtles with [color = white or color = blue and pcolor = red] [
    if immune-label != pflu-strain [
      set ant-distance (abs (immune-label - pflu-strain))
      set cross-immunity (natural-immunity * (1 - (ant-distance / antigenic-distance-limit)))
    if cross-immunity < 0 [set cross-immunity 0]
    if random 100 < (((100 - cross-immunity) / 100) * probability-of-infection)
      [set color red set infection-period 0 set infection-number infection-number + 1 set tflu-strain pflu-strain]
        ] 
  if immune-label = pflu-strain [ 
    if random 100 < (((100 - natural-immunity) / 100) * probability-of-infection)
      [set color red set infection-period 0 set infection-number infection-number + 1 set tflu-strain pflu-strain]
    ] 
]
end

to mutate ;; some probability of mutation (change in strain label) when an individual receives infection from a patch
  ifelse in-host [
    ask turtles with [color = red] [
     if random 100 < probability-of-mutation [
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      set tflu-strain (tflu-strain + (random (drift-size + 1)))]
      [set tflu-strain (tflu-strain - (random (drift-size + 1)))]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  [ask turtles with [color = red and infection-period = 0] [
     if random 100 < probability-of-mutation [
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      set tflu-strain (tflu-strain + (random (drift-size + 1)))]
      [set tflu-strain (tflu-strain - (random (drift-size + 1)))]
      ]
     ]
    ]
end

to update-immunity
  ask turtles with [color = red and infection-period = 0] [
    ifelse immune-labelling = "first-infection" [
  if immune-label = -999999999999 [
        set immune-label tflu-strain]]
  [set immune-label tflu-strain]
]
end

 to track-infecteds ;; turtles with given infection period should become uninfected
  ask turtles with [color = red] [
    set infection-period infection-period + 1
  if infection-period = age-infection-max [
    set color white set infection-period 0 set tflu-strain -999999999999
    ]
  ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
  set fomite-age fomite-age + 1
  if fomite-age > max-fomite-persistence [
  set pcolor black
    ]
  ]
end
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with the line

```
let vax-turtles (list turtles with [color = blue])
```

the `list` primitive creates a list, but not a list of `turtles with [color = blue]`.  Rather it creates a list of its arguments, which in this case is a single angentset.  You instead want a list of the agents **in** the agentset.  The `of` reporter is the easiest way to get that as `of` always returns a list.

```
let vax-turtles [self] of turtles with [color = blue]
```

Alternatively, if you wanted the list to be sorted, you could use `sort`, which also always returns a list.

```
let vax-turtles sort turtles with [color = blue]
```

As for the problem you describe in the comment below, you need to ask each vax-turtle to set its own vax-strain (which I assume is a turtles-own variable). Assuming that you are using NetLogo 6.x,

```
if vaccine = "HEV" [
    let vax-turtles [self] of turtles with [color = blue]
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue] 
    foreach [vax-turtles] [t ->
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      ask t [set vax-strain (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]]
    [ask t [set vax-strain (-1 * random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]]
      ]
    ]
```

But if drift-size is the same for all vax-turtles, it would be pretty unlikely that, given `random`, JenB's solution below would give the same value for vax-strain for any two turtles, would it not?

Comment: Getting an error:

this code can't be run by the observer, only a turtle
error while observer running SET
  called by (anonymous command from: procedure SETUP-TURTLES: [ifelse one-of [1 2] = 1 [ set vax-strain random 2 * drift-size + 1 ] [ set vax-strain -1 * random 2 * drift-size + 1 ] set vax-strain random 2 * drift-size + 1 set vax-strain -1 * random 2 * drift-size + 1 set immune-label vax-strain])

My code:
  if vaccine = "HEV" [
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue]
    let vax-turtles [self] of turtles with [color = blue]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I can't see why you need to do the iteration rather than ask and it is much cleaner to stick with ask. So, try replacing:

```
if vaccine = "HEV" [
    let vax-turtles (list turtles with [color = blue])
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue] 
    foreach [vax-turtles] [
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1) [
      set vax-strain (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
    [set vax-strain (-1 * random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))]
      ]
    ]
```

with

```
if vaccine = "HEV" [
    let vax-turtles turtles with [color = blue]
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue] 
    ask [vax-turtles] [
      ifelse (one-of [1 2] = 1)
      [ set vax-strain (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1)) ]
      [ set vax-strain (-1 * random ((2 * drift-size) + 1)) ]
    ]
  ]
```

For that matter, I think the different values are simply different signs of the same value, so you could do:

```
if vaccine = "HEV" [
    let vax-turtles turtles with [color = blue]
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white] [set color blue] 
    ask [vax-turtles] [
      set vax-strain one-of [-1 1] * (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))
    ]
  ]
```

Also, I am not sure if you are doing this intentionally, but you are changing the proportion to blue after creating the `vax-turtles` agentset. This means that the newly changed turtles will not be given a `vax-strain` until the next `tick` or whenever the code is next run. Furthermore, the code you have will assign a new `vax-strain` to all the blue turtles, even if they were made blue in a previous steps. If you actually want the `vax-strain` to be assigned once only and the turtle to change colour to show this, try:

```
if vaccine = "HEV" [
    ask n-of prop-vax turtles with [color = white]
    [ set color blue
      set vax-strain one-of [-1 1] * (random ((2 * drift-size) + 1))
      type "drift-size is " type drift-size type " and vax-strain is " print vax-strain ;; new line here for diagnostics
    ]
  ]
```

UPDATE: `ask` gives a new random number to each agent. You can see this by running the complete model:

```
turtles-own [testnum]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  [ set testnum random 5 ]
  print [testnum] of turtles
end
```

Comment: Hi JenB, I have to do iteration for HEV because each individual needs to receive a different vaccine. I tried some of the code you suggested but unfortunately all of the turtles are getting the same vaccine strain – this works well for the HOV condition, but not the HEV. I need to ensure that only blue turtles are being assigned a vaccine strain and that the strain is different for each individual in the HEV condition. Using ask doesn't seem to  do this because it assigns one vaccine strain to the whole agentset. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Actually, `ask` will give a new random number to each agent. I have written you a complete piece of code so you can see this. If all your turtles are getting assigned the same random number, there is a problem with your `random` call. What sort of values are in drift-size?

Comment: Thanks for the ask code! Drift size determines how "big" a mutation event is when a circulating virus mutates. The minimum is 0 and the maximum is 6, e.g. if drift size is 5 and a virus starts out as strain 0 it may mutate to 5 or -5. The vaccines I'm trying to implement would make individuals immune to particular strains using the same integer system.

Comment: Okay. I suggest you add some print statements or use the inspect window to have a look at some of your values and work backwards until you work out why your vax-strain are all coming out the same. I will add a line to start you off.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
foreach sort-on [who] turtles with [color = blue]
```

will suffice.